Can mutingpermissionset be used to restrict OWD settings?
Can mutingpermissionset be used to restrict OWD settings?
If for example, there is OWD Public Read Write on Account, can MutingPermissionSet be used to restrict View All permission for a certain user who has this MutingPermissionSet assigned?
